Reducing vacuum overhead & partitioning strategy for high-volume messages in PostgreSQL 13
I have a use case where I need to process a file containing messages generated for multiple customers. These messages need to be stored in a database and to be forwarded to respective customer in batches.
Once I receive an acknowledgment (which will be an individual response sent by customer for each message), I will pair the acknowledgment
with CORRELATION_ID and delete the corresponding message from db. If no acknowledgment is received, I will retry the same message to customer after every 10 mins until I get the acknowledgement or the message will expire. (lets say expiry = 10 days, I will retry till 10 days and if no acknowledgement is received then I will delete that message from db).
We typically receive an acknowledgment for 70-80% of the messages in the first attempt, for remaning message we cannot predict the behaviour, either we received the acknowledgment in mutiple retries or the message will get expired.
Additionally, each customer has a configuration (customerConfig) loaded during application startup. It has a field expiry w.r.t each message type and its dynamic which means customer can change these values at any moment. Sample below
[{
    "customer": "524AI9KS",
    "messages": [{
        "message_type": "Billing",
        "expiry ": "30"           // in days
      },
      {
        "message_type": "Promotional",
        "expiry ": "10"           // in days
      },
      {
        "message_type": "Support ",
        "expiry ": "15"           // in days
      }]
 },
 {
    "customer": "695AS5JW96",
    "messages": [{
        "message_type": "Billing",
        "expiry ": "40"           // in days
      },
      {
        "message_type": "Promotional",
        "expiry ": "12"           // in days
      },
      {
        "message_type": "Support ",
        "expiry ": "11"           // in days
      }]
}]

Below is the current database script
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_MESSAGES (
    CUSTOMER_ID         VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE_ID          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE_TYPE        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    CORRELATION_ID      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    RETRY_COUNT         NUMERIC(10, 0)  NOT NULL,
    CRTE_TS             TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
    UPTS_TS             TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE             VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_MESSAGES_PK PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID, MESSAGE_ID)
) PARTITION BY HASH (CUSTOMER_ID);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_MESSAGES_P0 PARTITION OF CUSTOMER_MESSAGES FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 0);
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_MESSAGES_P1 PARTITION OF CUSTOMER_MESSAGES FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 1);
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_MESSAGES_P2 PARTITION OF CUSTOMER_MESSAGES FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 2);
...
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_MESSAGES_P9 PARTITION OF CUSTOMER_MESSAGES FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 9);

Message & acknowledgement pairing is done based on on CORRELATION_ID.
Above partitioning strategy was chosen when the message volume was small (less than 50,000 per day) and there were only 20 customers. Now, the message volume has grown to around 15-20 million per day, and there are about 10,000 customers.
The problem with the current design is that

It creates a lot of "vacuum" or empty space that leads to fragmentaion in db and ultimately will impact the query performance.
One parition will end up having lots of message, as messages distribution is based on customer. It may be possible that one customer is have 30-45% volumne at a given period.

We also considered partitioning by CRTE_TS (instead of CUSTOMER_ID) so that we can drop partitions after the retention period. However, since the retention period varies for each customer and for each message type, it can be challenging to implement.
I am using PostgreSQL 13 and backend application is in spring boot.
Can someone suggest, which partitioning strategy I should go with ? (given that PostgreSQL allows partitioning by RANGE, HASH, or LIST) and on which column should you create the partition?

Do you purge a message as soon as it is acknowledged or only after the retention period?

Hi @RichardHuxton, we purge the message from db as soon as we receive the acknowledged, if we don't get the acknowledged we replay this message to customer continuesly in certain interval.  Lastly when the retention period is elasped then we purge from db.

Can you quantity "a lot of empty space"?  Are you we talking about 99% empty, or 20% empty?  And what makes you think that this is leading to performance problems?  If you have performance problems, you should describe them directly, not by describing what you think might be causing them.

Hi @jjanes, since I am storing all messages in the database & and for 70% of messages, I am getting acknowledgement in first attempt, so I am deleting those messages directly from the database. This is creating lots of holes / empty spaces which leads to fragmentation in database and because of this to query execution will take longer time and it will increase I/O operations. Considering huge volume (around 15 million per day).

https://dba.stackexchange.com/

VACUUM is a process, not disk space or so. You state that deleting records creates empty space, which will be used for new records for the same table. The vacuum process (autovacuum) releases these dead tuples. How did you configure autovacuum? And what does pg_stat_user_tables tell you about dead tuples and (auto-)vacuum? You can also partition each partition into subpartitions based on the timestamp. But for now, I don't see any problem, not even a performance problem has been presented.

But again fragmentation is not a performance problem.  It is a conjecture about something which might be causing a performance problem (and a conjecture which is likely wrong), but with no description of the performance problem.  Is the space not getting reused?  Is it getting reused but in doing so is breaking up natural correlations/clustering in the data?  Is the real problem in fragmentation of the indexes, not the table?

Since the messages are only stored temporarily, a high volume of "vacuum" is to be expected. That is the nature of your use case in combination with how Postgres works. (It would be different for Oracle.)
With the current partitioning strategy, you are basically trying to equally distribute the load across several partitions. This likely does not address your performance issues. It does not help either for deletion after the retention period since the partitions are shared by multiple customers and continue to receive new data. Most likely, your system would not be any slower without the partitions.
Without additional information about your data (statistical data about how long it takes until a message is acknowledged, how many times messages are retries etc.) and about your performance problem (slow inserts vs slow updates vs long running jobs vs lock contention etc.), it is difficult to propose a better partitioning strategy. But most successful partitioning strategies separate hot from cold data. That way the cache is well used by the hot data, and the cold data mostly stays out of the cache.
So a possible strategy could be to separate by number of retries and/or creation data (the later one with rolling partitions). This would make sense if most of the messages are quickly acknowledged and the time between retries increases. It will not be easy to make this work as you can no longer have a unique key on CUSTOMER_ID and MESSAGE_ID.
But then again, your problem might be completely different and changing the partition strategy might not help. You are saying that message acknowledgement is by correlation ID but you did not mention an index for it. Maybe updating the table just to record the retries is the problem (it will create a new version of each updated row, generating a lot of work for vacuum). This could be solved differently.

How much work VACUUM does (most likely autovacuum) also depends on the configuration. Updating records could even reduce the amount of work for autovacuum, for example, when facilitating HOT updates. Without details, we can't answer the unknown question. There are some observations, but no problem has been mentioned.
